# Redirect Subdomain That is Not on SSL

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, apache-2.4, subdomain

I have a SSL certificate that is installed on the server that only covers the domain, not subdomains

All traffic is redirected using apache config file

When I set up the subdomain to redirect a subdomain you get the browser alerting you that the site isn't safe because the SSL doesn't match the domain. I want to catch the subdomain before it gets forced to  HTTPS and redirect it to where I need it to go because once its forced to HTTPS it throws an error

My apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName aliahealthcare.com
   Redirect permanent / https://aliahealthcare.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     //blah
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, SSL doesn't work that way.  Every new domain you go to will have a new DNS lookup and a new SSL handshake and the certificate will be verified each time.  If you think about it, that's a really good thing for security!  (Despite inconveniencing you in this situation)

Your best bet is to get a wildcard cert or use Subject Alternate Names.

Comment: so I can't catch the subdomain before the redirect to https?

Comment: if a user goes to http://www.aliahealthcare.com and you want to redirect it to https://aliahealthcare.com you can do that.  But you can't redirect https://www.aliahealthcare.com to https://aliahealthcare.com nor can you redirect http://www.aliahealthcare.com to https://www.aliahealthcare.com without getting certificate errors if your cert is only for aliahealthcare.com

Comment: I think your http/https part of each url got cut off unless my browser is auto detecting the links and changing the name

Comment: but what you are saying is I can redirect http://aliahealthcare.com to https://aliahealthcare.com but I can't redirect to http://email.aliahealthcare.com to https://gmail.com

Comment: you can redirect http://email.aliahealthcare.com to gmail.com since gmail.com has a valid cert.  but you can't redirect https://email.aliahealthcare.com to gmail.com since your cert doesn't cover email.aliahealthcare.com.  but as long as users come in on http that will work

Comment: If you have defined a `HSTS` policy with ìncludeSubdomains` attribute, the browser will enforce HTTPS before even making the initial connection to the web server.